# Refused to get unsafe header "x-parse-job-status-id" - AngularJs and Parse Server

Tags: html, angularjs, parse-platform

After months of working without any trouble, now when trying to make login, this error appears. The code shown is simplified, when it arrives at "Parse.User.logIn" is when the error happens. There are some similar questions here, but all of them are related to CORS, and I don´t know how or where to make something like the line below:

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-parse-job-status-id

CODE:

```
$scope.signin = function () {
    var email = $scope.login.email;
    var pass = $scope.login.pass;            
    Parse.User.logIn(email, pass, {
        success: function (user) {
            Stuff after successful login                  

                }
            });
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
                stuff after unsuccessful login
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix can be found here. We tried it and worked like a charm

https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/622

**Edit:**

Solution (can be found in link)

"I believe you're using the unpkg version:

https://unpkg.com/parse/dist/parse.js, and the minified production version is at https://unpkg.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js.

Which is automatically pointing to the latest release, you should use:

https://unpkg.com/parse@1.11.1/dist/parse.js

As you are now pointing to the SDK v2.0 which contains that issue."